# Wondering how to properly grant privileges to created users on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-grant

I am creating some users on SQL server but I am a little confused as to whether I grant "alter any login" or "alter any linked server"  to my LOGIN  or to the USER account?

As you all know, on SQL server, you create users in this order:

1. Create LOGIN sysUser1  (in master db)
2. Create USER myUser1 for LOGIN sysUser1  (in users db)
3. CREATE SCHEMA myUser1 AUTHORIZATION myUser1
4. then, run sp_addrolemember for myUser1 as needed
5. then, do grants

I am confused as to whether I should:

1. grant alter any login to myUser1

or

1. grant alter any login to sysUser1

Can anyone clarify?  Am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER LOGIN is a server level permission, so you can't grant it to database users. You need to grant it to sysUser1 in your case.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx

Edit: Dito for linked server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That helped a lot. :-)   Here is a variation of my script:  https://gist.github.com/3792028

Answer (score 0):

Logins and Linked Servers are both objects that exist at the instance level, as opposed to at the database level, so these permissions both need to be applied to the login, rather than the user.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then it is possible to create you own Instance level roles, but in 2008 and below, you are rrestricted to the built in server roles.

There is a server role called setupadmin that lets members manage linked servers.